# Unable to extract substring from larger mutli-line string in Swift

Tags: html, swift, xcode

I extracted some HTML code and it's stored in a string called "html". I want to pull the number of stars from this HTML code. Looking at the html, I thought the easiest way was to look for the word "stars" in the html string and go from there. So I wrote this code:

```
var s = "stars"
if (html.contains(s)) {
   print("Found stars")
}
```

However, for some reason this does not work and it does not print "Found Stars" in the bottom right part of xcode. What am I doing wrong?

Here is part of the html code that is stored in the html string variable

```html
</h2>
<div class="a-row a-size-small a-color-secondary"><span class="a-size-small" dir="auto">by </span><span class="a-size-small" dir="auto">John Bolton</span></div>
                    </div>
                    
                        <div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-mini">
                            <div class="a-row a-size-small">


<span aria-label="3.1 out of 5 stars">
    

<i class="a-icon a-icon-star-small a-star-small-3 aok-align-bottom"><span class="a-icon-alt">3.1 out of 5 stars</span></i>

</span>
```

Here is the code I am using to extract the HTML:

```
            var html = ""
            let scheme = "https"
            let host = "www.amazon.com"
            let path = "/s"
            let k =  ocrText
            let i = "stripbooks"
            let kItem = URLQueryItem(name: "k", value: k)
            let iItem = URLQueryItem(name: "i", value: i)
            
            var urlComponents = URLComponents()
            urlComponents.scheme = scheme
            urlComponents.host = host
            urlComponents.path = path
            urlComponents.queryItems = [kItem, iItem]
            
            guard let url = urlComponents.url else { return }
            
            print(url)
            
            
            
            //URL(string: "https://www.amazon.com" + "/s?k=" + text   + "&i=stripbooks")!
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data else {
                    print(error ?? "")
                    return
                }
                html = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
```

I think it might be that the .contains method is only checking the first line of the HTML, but I may be wrong.

Some more code regarding the rating:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                    guard let data = data else {
                        print(error ?? "")
                        return
                    }
                    html = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
                    let pattern = #"(\d.\d) out of 5 stars"#
                    if let range = html.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) {
                        let rating = html[range].prefix(3)
                        ocrText = ocrText + rating
                        print("testing", ocrText)
                    }
                    
                }.resume()
                
                print("LATER:", ocrText)
                
                
                
                
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.ocrTextView.text = ocrText
                    self.scanButton.isEnabled = true
                }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217049/discussion-on-question-by-oofmeister27-unable-to-extract-substring-from-larger-m).

Answer (score 0):

Create the `html` `String` like below,

```
let html = """
</h2>
<div class="a-row a-size-small a-color-secondary"><span class="a-size-small" dir="auto">by </span><span class="a-size-small" dir="auto">John Bolton</span></div>
                    </div>
                    
                        <div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-mini">
                            <div class="a-row a-size-small">


<span aria-label="3.1 out of 5 stars">
    

<i class="a-icon a-icon-star-small a-star-small-3 aok-align-bottom"><span class="a-icon-alt">3.1 out of 5 stars</span></i>

</span>
"""
```

Now the below code will print Found stars in your console.

```
var s = "stars"
if (html.contains(s)) {
   print("Found stars")
}
```

Comment: i don't know who downvoted your answer, but it works, i just tested it

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the thing is I am using URLSession.shared.dataTask to extract the html from the amazon website. I have updated the OP with the my code that actually extracts the html. The html stored in the html string doesn't only contain the "stars" part you mentioned in your answer, it contains the whole html.

Comment: So I don't think "hardcoding" the string would work...

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are storing the string with escaping special characters (i.e replacing " to \") like so:

```
var str = "</h2> <div class=\"a-row a-size-small a-color-secondary\"><span class=\"a-size-small\" dir=\"auto\">by </span><span class=\"a-size-small\" dir=\"auto\">John Bolton</span></div></div><div class=\"a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-mini\"><div class=\"a-row a-size-small\"><span aria-label=\"3.1 out of 5 stars\"><i class=\"a-icon a-icon-star-small a-star-small-3 aok-align-bottom\"><span class=\"a-icon-alt\">3.1 out of 5 stars</span></i></span>"
```